# Acceder a la bd mysql de hostinger

Tags: javascript, mysql, nodejs, express, hosting

Cuando quiero acceder a la bd de hostinger me tira el siguiente error
El error de conexion es Error: ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_AUTH_MODE: Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client .
Estoy usando nodejs y express e intentando acceder con

```
const conexion = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'u125133381_matear',
    password: 'Diego448',
    database: 'u125133381_adminmatear',
})
```

De forma local se que con ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password'; y flush privileges;
se soluciona pero no se como hacer eso intentando acceder a la base de datos en hostinger
alguna solucion ?

Answer (score 0):

creo que la respuesta que dan en este hilo seria la mas adecuada para este caso [how does createConnection work with nodeJS in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40153085/how-does-createconnection-work-with-nodejs-in-mysql)

Adjunto también la traducción automática

---

Puede crear un grupo de conexiones en un módulo y luego compartir ese grupo en todos sus módulos, llamando pool.getConnection()siempre que lo necesite. Eso podría ser mejor que mantener una única conexión compartida abierta todo el tiempo.

Un proyecto en el que estoy trabajando hace esto:

utils / database.js

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var pool = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit: 100,
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'xxxxx',
    password: 'yyyyy',
    database: 'zzzzz',
    debug: false
});

module.exports = pool
```

cuentas.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var pool = require('./utils/database');

router.get('/', function(req, res) {

    pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {

        // do whatever you want with your connection here

        connection.release();

    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

---

Otra forma en la que estoy jugando es así:

utils / database.js

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var pool = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit: 100,
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'xxxxx',
    password: 'yyyyy',
    database: 'zzzzz',
    debug: false
});

var getConnection = function(callback) {
    pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
        callback(err, connection);
    });
});

module.exports = getConnection;
```

cuentas.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var createConnection = require('./utils/database');

router.get('/', function(req, res) {

    createConnection(function(err, connection) {

        // do whatever you want with your connection here

        connection.release();

    });
});

module.exports = router;
```